# How to partition a 16TB table with 3 billion rows within a maintenance window?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I've inherited a large table (16TB, 3 billion rows, lot of ntext data), that's never been partitioned. I want to split it over set of filegroups. Current estimate based on limited test is about 70 hours for the index re-create. I'm aware of RESUMABLE, but I think that doesn't solve the problem of trying to squeeze operations into 12 weekly maintenance window and reads wouldn't work properly ...

Any options to achieve this?

Also tried to slice off only the oldest data in test, that doesn't seem to matter, I'm assuming all data gets rewritten. Table has ntext, so columnar possible(?). Free space - not much, couple TB at most.

I'm seeing cutting over to a limited copy with most recent data and then restitching it somehow as only option? Would appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Why do you need to partition it?

Comment: +1 to Erik's question. 3B rows isn't particularly large, but it sounds like you have very wide rows from the ntext data (which is deprecated as a data type). Depending on your goals, _vertical_ partitioning could be the most valuable option.

Comment: @ErikDarling thanks both - it’s to enable us to restore only more recent data in non-prod environments and allow fast restore of recent data in case of production rebuild which is a requirement from regulator under cyber scenarios. Also can’t run DBCC :)